# iOS In App Purchases using a Test Account

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In App Purchasing and I am testing it using Sandbox Accounts, now here is what I do:

- Sign out of iTunes in Settings
- Close my App
- Open the App and press the "Purchase" Button which adds the Product from StoreKit to the queue (and brings up a popup to sign in)

Now when the "Sign in" Popup appears, I can choose from "Use an existing Apple ID" and "Create a new Account". I have an existing account, which is the Sandbox account from itunesconnect.apple.com

I enter my credentials and after a few seconds, the same popup appears again.
It is asking me twice to sign in, and after signing in twice via this alert, it pops up another alert, where I only need to enter the password for this sandbox account.

Several popups follow which notify you about the subscription and all, those are fine I guess, but this multiple sign up popups are confusing.

So, has anyone experienced the same issue and is it only a sandbox thing, or will it also happen in production when you sign up with a new account?

Any information in regards to it are appreciated :)

- xCoder

Comment: As far as I have worked on the IAPs, this is how they work in the Sandbox environment, where they ask you a couple of times to login for the very first time, and then it asks for password

Comment: And also make sure that you are not calling the payment method twice on the tap of the button.